# ReactのRouteHandlerが反応しない

Tags: reactjs

React-Routerを使おうとしているのですが、
RouteHandlerで呼び出されるはずのDOMが表示されません。

HTML:https://github.com/hideokamoto/wp-react/blob/master/index.html
JS：https://github.com/hideokamoto/wp-react/blob/master/src/app.js

https://github.com/koba04/react-server-side-rendering-sample/blob/master/components/top.js
などを見る限りcreateClassしてXMLをreturnすれば大丈夫そうかと思ったのですが、

```js
var Inbox
var Calendar
var Dashboard
```

それぞれに記述したタグだけが表示されない状態ですので、
上記の３変数に問題があるのかなと思うのですがどなたかご教授頂けないでしょうか・・・？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

`var App`より先にInboxやDashboardなどの値を定義すればOKなだけです。